# AS3 - Can't use SharedObject?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For some reason, when trying to see if it's working I get TypeError:

> Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "[object
>   SharedObject]1" to flash.net.SharedObject.

Here is my code:

```
stop();

var savedstuff:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myStuff");

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvent);

function enterFrameEvent (event:Event){
  savedstuff += 1;
  trace (savedstuff);
}

bootoon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicks);

function clicks (event:MouseEvent){
  gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a property called **data** from the shared object in order to save and load variables locally.

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savedata");
var foo:uint = so.data.foo ? so.data.foo : 0; // If there is a foo property then load it, otherwise set it to zero.
foo++;

so.data.foo = foo; // Save foo to the shared object
trace(foo); // Should increase the value of foo with every launch of the application

//so.clear(); // If you ever want to reset shared object call this.
```